# Gigabit ports on Dell Powerconnect 2324 never worked

Tags: dell, switch, gigabit-ethernet, dell-powerconnect

I have a [Dell Powerconnect 2324](http://www.dell.com/us/en/corp/networking/pwcnt_2324/pd.aspx?refid=pwcnt_2324&s=corp) with Gigabit ports - 24 ports 10/100 ports with 2 Gigabit ports - that never worked. It's supposed to auto-detect everything, but even trying different combinations I never get any lights or connection on the 2 Gigabit ports. I've always wired my uplink into the normal 10/100 ports (which always works, whatever the configuration of cables). I've seen this problem reported by a couple of other people on the Internet with no solution. Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

For some reason the [manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/pc2xxx/en/ug/22xx23xxbk0.pdf) doesn't seem to be linked from that page. I only have one other port connected, and I've tried it in several. The Gigabit ports *are* 10/100 compatible and I would think auto-sensing (not stated explicitly, but says all ports are MDI/MDIX sensing and auto-speed/duplex). If not auto-sensing, then there is no information about how to configure the switch (it is unmanaged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old post, I know.

I just diagnosed pretty much the same thing.

The gigabit ports *cannot* do 10/100, in spite of what the user's manual says about it.

I found another [document](http://www.crash-bg.com/CATALOG/drugi/Dell_powerconnect_2324.pdf), which can be found by googling "K5672A00.fm". It appears to be an erratum for the manual regarding this specific issue.

This one indicates that the gig ports are 1000-ONLY. They are not triple-speed ports. From that document:

> Connect only 1000Base-T full-duplex capable devices to ports 25 or 26 on the PowerConnect2324 switch

Answer (score 1):

I believe those two gigabit ports are probably shared with port 23 & 24 of the 10/100 ports.  Make sure those are empty if you're trying to use the gigabit side.

Comment: A lot of the lower end switches do this.  I have two HP Procurve 1824-24G that share port 23 and 24 with the multi purpose slots.

Comment: From the product FAQ at Dell:
Are the uplinks on the PowerConnect 2324 switch so-called "combo ports"?
No. The Gigabit Ethernet links on the PowerConnect 2324 switch are standalone ports. A full 26 ports of connectivity are available.

Comment: Well, then that's definitely not it.  Are you comfortable logging into the console of this switch?

Comment: I would be, if I knew how.

Answer (score 1):

its a brandname switch, which has to be supported byt the vendor, so why not call Dell and ask?

Comment: it's not common that you get a total dud so my first assumption was ignorance on my part. plus my experience with calling is that they tell me to clear my cookies or some other BS. i didn't have time to sort it out when it was new (we weren't using the bandwidth) now it's a few years old, maybe isn't supported. of course i will check if there's no other possibility.

Comment: I have worked in Dell Server/Switch support. You get extremely professional people there. This is NOT the local ISP support who will ask you to reboot everything and clear the cookies - this is an experienced sysadmin who will try to help you out, and if he cannot, he will escalate to a very good networking expert. Seriously, the guys in the networking support there are real gurus.

Comment: Marked this correct, although I never got around to trying it it's probably the right way to go. Now the switch has completely stopped working (power, presumably).

Answer (score 0):

David, looking at the spec sheet you linked, I see that the gigabit ethernet ports are not listed as 'plug and play' or 'autosensing'.  So you may have to manually configure them via the console or web admin page.

A good chance you'll do that with:

```
#              configure

(config)#      interface ethernet g1

(config-if)    no shutdown
(config-if)    duplex full
(config-if)    speed 1000
```

If that doesn't help, try displaying all your interface statuses.  This will also help if you don't know the name/number of the gig-E ports.
`#              show interface status`

Comment: They could also be gigabit only which would not work when plugged into a 10/100 switch on the other end.

Comment: The manual says they are 10/100/1000 and seems to imply auto-sensing. See update - no indication of how to configure it.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize this was an unmanaged switch.  I know you mentioned different combinations of connections.  Does that include different types of devices (PC and/or router, instead of a switch) and different cabling? (crossover and regular)  And of course, all the random permutations thereof.

Comment: I've tried a few combinations, not 100% sure I've covered them all but think so. All ports are specified in all Dell documents as auto-everything.